Concept for std::variant and enclosed types using std::get
I tried writing a concept to see if a particular type is in a std::variant type list but the concept surprisingly passes while the code fails to compile if I have same the expression outside of the concept.
#include <variant>
#include <string>

template <typename T, typename Variant>
concept Concept = requires(Variant v) {
    { std::get<T>(v) };
};

int main() {
    using V = std::variant<int, float>;

    static_assert(Concept<std::string, V>);  // this is true (does not get fired)

    V v(42);
   // std::get<std::string>(v);  // this does not compile though

    return 0;
}

Am I using concepts the correct way here?

The concept verifies that there is such function, and there is. It doesn't verify if that function contains a static_assert saying that the parameter types are wrong.

std::get (variant) is not SFINAE friendly.
